# Android: RestAPI protocol not found - an issue with my string / url

Tags: java, android, string, rest, url

In my app, I am calling a rest api command via an async task class I have made.

When I pass the string through the async task call like this

```
apiRequest = new APIRequest();
apiRequest.execute("https:api.my/api/url");
```

I get "Protocol not found: [Ljava.lang.String;@f51e848? ... ]" where the ... is the rest of my api call.

Inside my async class:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(str + responseFormat + "&api_key=" + apiKey);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

With this method, I get the error shown above. ***However***, when I cut the string out of the apiRequest call, and paste it directly into the async task, it works perfectly.

---

Below, code is working with the cut and paste of the url.

```
apiRequest = new APIRequest();
apiRequest.execute();
```

Inside my async class:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https:api.my/api/url" + responseFormat + "&api_key=" + apiKey);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: str parameter is an Array I believe, str[0] would be your Url

Comment: Agreed, see [Arbitrary Number of Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs)  or simply remove the 3 dots

Comment: Thanks guys, that did it. Had no idea it was being passed through as an array.